Execute permissions for a file on an ISO
I have an ISO I have mounted and the files can be browsed from Windows via the Samba share however I am unable to execute a program on the ISO as Windows reports I do not have permission. I have checked the files permissions and see the ISO only has read access.
Whilst I do not need write access I do need to be able to execute programs on the ISO.
The ISO permissions are:
root@SVR11298:/srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-4dd07498-fa7a-41ab-a25f-6c5d28fc47e9/public/isos/myiso# ls -l
total 11074
dr-xr-xr-x 7 nobody nogroup     364 Feb 15  2022 3rdParty
-r--r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup 8326848 Jan 25  2023 autorun.aru
-r--r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup 2981888 Feb 21  2018 autorun.exe
-r--r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup    9158 Feb  1  2005 autorun.ico
-r--r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup      67 Jul 17  2018 autorun.inf
dr-xr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup     192 Oct 27  2022 Bin
dr-xr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup    1300 Feb 15  2022 Documents
dr-xr-xr-x 6 nobody nogroup     540 Feb 15  2022 Install
dr-xr-xr-x 4 nobody nogroup     640 Feb 15  2022 Prerequisites
dr-xr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup     452 Feb 15  2022 Utilities
-r--r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup    5619 Jan 16  2023 valid.md5
root@SVR11298:/srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-4dd07498-fa7a-41ab-a25f-6c5d28fc47e9/public/isos/myiso#

In /etc/fstab I have mounted the ISO as shown below:
/home/1.12.0.998DVD.iso /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-4dd07498-fa7a-41ab-a25f-6c5d28fc47e9/public/isos/myiso auto loop 0 0


looks like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188721/execute-a-exe-on-a-samba-share
